# Wasserstein distance for categorical data? Relationship to TVD?

Tags: distributions, distance, wasserstein

Is the Wasserstein distance applicable for categorical data? e.g. if we have the distribution of different coloured balls in two bags,

```
bag_1 = {"red": 0.33, "blue": 0.33, "green": 0.33}
bag_2 = {"red": 0.45, "blue": 0.20, "green": 0.35}
```

we can use measures like TVD to compare the two bags. From my understanding, TVD makes more sense here as TVD works on non-metric spaces while Wasserstein is not (e.g. according to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0209021.pdf)).

The paper does describe a relationship between TVD and Wasserstein but I'm a little confused... and wondering what the benefit of the Wasserstein distance is, especially for non-metric data like these. Would love your comments, thanks!

Comment: What does "TVD" stand for?

Comment: Total variation distance :)

Comment: Indeed, the Wasserstein distance makes more sense for metric spaces, and this is amongst others simply because it **uses** the metric between symbols in its definition (contrary to the TVD that only uses the probabilities of the symbols). However, this also means that when you are working on a **non metric space** like here, it's not even possible to **define** the Wasserstein distance between those two distrbutions.